# PHP arrays Output Format

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array `( D,d,d,e,f,g,d,d,d,d)`

The output should be like below.

Values may change but format should not change. I am unable to print like this format. How to get like below using php arrays? Values may change but format should not change. I am unable to print like this format. How to get like below using php arrays?

```
1 - d
2 - d
3 - d
4 - e
4 - e
5 - f
5 - f
6 - g
6 - g
7 - d
8 - d
9 - d
10 -d
```

How to get like this? Please help me.

Comment: Should the output have an order/ pattern?

Comment: yes line by line like 1-d next line 2-d next line 3-d like that

Comment: I mean you have 1x e in your array but output it 2x times?

Comment: ya i need that format u can change values and take arrays finally my result will b like that...thank u

Comment: You are going to have to describe in a lot more detail just how your initial data becomes your final output. Why are there two of e, f and g in your output but only one of each in your input, and why are the indexes repeated for them?

Comment: actually they given me a task...this task should be in this format...they said u take arrays and get o/p like this...

Comment: *"actually they given me a task"* and we are supposed to build it for you? That's no longer "your" task now, is it?

Comment: `foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value) { echo "Figure out this part yourself\n" ;}`

Comment: but it is giving like this1_d
2_d
3_d
4_e
5_f
6_g
7_d
8_d
9_d
10_d my output is not like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array = array("D", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "d", "d", "d", "d");
    $array = array_map('strtolower', $array);
    $counts = array_count_values($array);

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {

        if(strtolower($counts[$v]) == 1)
            echo $k+1 . " - " . $v . "<br />";
        echo $k+1 . " - " . $v . "<br />";

    }

?>
```

Output:

```
1 - d
2 - d
3 - d
4 - e
4 - e
5 - f
5 - f
6 - g
6 - g
7 - d
8 - d
9 - d
10 - d
```

Comment: I'm not the down-voter but potentially because answering questions that are unclear/incomplete is generally discouraged?

Comment: @winterblood could be! But i help where i can and if i understand a question i want to help!

Comment: @Arun How you can upvote and why you should upvote see/read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up